# How do I run a Exchange 2007 PowerShell script from the command line?

Tags: command-line, powershell, vbscript, batch-file, exchange-server-2007

I have a very basic PowerShell script called MyScript.ps1 that runs quite happily in the Exchange Management Shell:

`Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | where { $_.Mounted -eq $True }`

If I try to run `powershell.exe MyScript.ps1` it complains because it can't find the Get-MailboxDatabase cmdlet.  I'm guessing PowerShell and the Exchange Management Shell are running slightly differently?

**How do I run an Exchange-based PowerShell script from the command line?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the Exchange management snapin before you can run Exchange scripts from the command line.  I believe the code would be like so:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
```

Comment: Answered in under 5 minutes - puts ExpertSexchange to shame! Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad to help.  That is one of those things that will get you at least once when you are working with Powershell.